# Subclass of TextView and text color

Tags: android, textview

I'm trying to implement a subclass of TextView that prints the text vertically rotated, but I'm having troubles printing the text in the color I specify from an XML layout. The class code is:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.text.TextPaint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class VerticalTextView extends TextView {
    private Rect bounds = new Rect();
    private TextPaint textPaint;

    public VerticalTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public VerticalTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        textPaint = getPaint();
        textPaint.getTextBounds((String) getText(), 0, getText().length(), bounds);
        setMeasuredDimension((int) (bounds.height() + textPaint.descent()), bounds.width());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.rotate(-90, bounds.width(), 0);
        canvas.drawText((String) getText(), 0, -bounds.width() + bounds.height(), textPaint);
    }
}
```

I have no need of custom properties for this view, so I'm not declaring a styleable for it.

I'm using this view in my activity by this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <com.verticaltextview.VerticalTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World" android:textColor="#ff0000ff"
        android:textStyle="italic" />
</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see, I'm specifying both the text color (blue) and the text style (italic), but only the style is applied, as the text is printed in black. If in the `onDraw()` method I hardcode a color by doing `textPaint.setColor(0xff00ff00)`, then the text is correctly printed in color.

Suggestions? Thanks ;)

Comment: Try RGB android:textColor="#0000FF" , you don't need to declare the alpha channel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to change the constructors of your `VerticalTextView` to the following:

```
private int         col     = 0xFFFFFFFF;

public VerticalTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs); // was missing a parent
    col = getCurrentTextColor();
}
```

Then add

```
textPaint.setColor(col);
```

to your `onDraw()` function.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Surely his constructor that passes the XML attribute set to the super will deal with the text color xml atribute?

Comment: You're right, Blundell. I've corrected my answer to a much simpler one :) ... thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Thanks, this worked, but why is it necessary to set the color for the Paint like this? Shouldn't it be done automatically by the 'super' constructor?

Comment: Since you are explicitly drawing the text yourself, the parent class has no idea about this. PS. Please mark the answer as the right one.

Comment: Yes, but I'm using the TextPaint object from the parent instance to draw the text, which should be set up with the attributes from the XML by the constructor, and besides in the code I posted the 'italic' attribute is correctly applied, the problem seems to be confined to the color only.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can get color in:

```
**public VerticalTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}**
```

then set this color to textPaint.